# Lack of object rotation when using three.js to import collada file

Tags: transformation, three.js, collada

I'm very new to the three.js javascript library and 3D work in general, anyway...

I've created a very simple scene with Blender and exported it as a collada (.dae) file. When it comes to importing it using the three.js collada loader (using THREE.ColladaLoader) the objects in my scene appear but the rotations are not applied.

For example I've got some cylinders in my scene, some I've drawn and not manipulated, some I've copied from the original and some that I've copied from the original and then rotated through 90 degrees. All of the objects appear but the ones that were rotated through 90 degrees in the scene are not shown rotated. It's as if the rotations are being applied.

Had a quick look at the .dae file and the rotation information seems to be in there. When previewing the .dae file with another tool all seems ok. I've even tried a very simple scene with a stretched cuboid which has been rotated. The cuboid shape is correct when viewed in browser but the rotation is not applied.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry bit late now but think it was r47 of the master branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. It was an issue with the three.js library. Found out about this on the mr.doob github pages, see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/771

Downloaded the three.js dev branch from github, rather than the master branch, and all is well.